# What product represents the solution to the system?

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

What product represents the solution to the system? $$-y+7x=14$$ $$-x+4y=1$$
I have that $y=\cfrac{7}{9}$ $x=\cfrac{19}{9}$

But how to place this as a setup of a product of two matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the system as

$$\begin{bmatrix} 7 & -1 \\ -1 &4 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 14 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

You can try to use a matrix method to solve the system again.

Answer (score 1):

$${7\ \ -1 \choose -1\ \ 4}{x \choose y} = {14 \choose 1}$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
7 & -1\\
-1 & 4
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x\\
y
\end{matrix}
\right]
=\left[
\begin{matrix}
14 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right].
\end{align}
Then, 
\begin{align}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x\\
y
\end{matrix}
\right]
=&\left[
\begin{matrix}
7 & -1\\
-1 & 4
\end{matrix}
\right]^{-1}\left[
\begin{matrix}
14 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right]\notag\\
=&\left[
\begin{matrix}
\frac{19}{9} \\
\frac{7}{9}
\end{matrix}
\right].
\end{align}